# OpenVPN portforwarding help for BitTorrent on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, iptables, openvpn, vpn, bittorrent

I own a VPS running Ubuntu 20.04. It currently has a running OpenVPN service I got going using this guide which uses a script https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-linux-14-04-or-16-04-lts/. I am able to connect to and use the VPN no trouble. The problem is that BitTorrent requires port forwarding to work well and this current implementation obviously does not work. I'd like to use port 30050. I have tried following this guide https://whattheserver.com/openvpn-server-with-port-forwarding/ additionally to set up port forwarding.

I have also configured my personal router to forward the BT port to my OpenVPN client PC (Windows 10) which has a static IP assigned (not sure if I needed to do this part, please let me know if I didn't need to).

This is what iptables -S produces on the OpenVPN VPS:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 10.8.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 30050 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 10.8.0.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 30050 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

Could anyone kindly instruct me on how to solve this? Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

There is no restriction (closed/dropped/rejected ports) on your VM iptables, all ports are opened and can be used on your VPN client.

You need to check the infrastructure firewall as well if there is one (your VPS provider interface).

And lastly you may enable IP forwarding details are available in [this article](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-turn-on-off-ip-forwarding-in-linux).